# How to correctly apply type for this during .call() method?

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble trying to figure out a solution for the following

```
interface IName {
  name:string;
}

let obj1:IName = {
  name: "LINUS"  
}


function profileInfo (age:number,location:string):string{
  return `${this.name} is ${age} years old and is from ${location}` // << Error here  as 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation
}

// call
let res = profileInfo.call(obj1,23,'Bangkok')
console.log(res);
```

I was experimenting with the call method which actually will bind the obj1 with the profileInfo function.

Any suggestion or solution is much appreciated.

The code does work on normal js though.

Comment: *"... the call method which actually will bind the obj1 with the profileInfo function."* It won't *bind* it, no. But it will call `profileInfo` with `this` set to the first argument you pass `call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) annotation:

```
function profileInfo(this: IName, age: number, location: string): string {
    return `${this.name} is ${age} years old and is from ${location}`
}
```

Note this will expose errors where you call `profileInfo` without the expected `this` context:

```
// Bad call:
profileInfo(23, 'Amsterdam'); // Error: The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'IName'.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the info and the link to the documentation and tip! Cheers